# Org-mode how to automatically adjust sub-entry completion with sub-sub-entry completions

Tags: org-mode, todo

I just very recently started using Emacs Org-mode to organize my tasks, and I really don't know anything about Emacs-Lisp.

What I have achieved is to mark a TODO entry as `DONE` when its children(sub-entry) are marked `DONE` by putting these commands in my Init file as instructed by the Org-mode manual.

```
(defun org-summary-todo (n-done n-not-done)
  "Switch entry to DONE when all subentries are done,
to TODO otherwise."       
  (let (org-log-done org-log-states) ;turn off logging                          
    (org-todo (if (= n-not-done 0) "DONE" "TODO"))))                             
(add-hook 'org-after-todo-statistics-hook #'org-summary-todo)
```

However, this doesn't work when I want it to change the status of a child(sub-entry) based on this child's child(sub-sub-entry). Effectively, I have this following TODO list:

```
* Testing[0%]                                                                   
** TODO Item1[100%]                                                             
*** DONE Item1.1...                                                             
*** DONE Item1.2...                                                             
** TODO Item2[0%]                                                               
*** TODO Item2.1                                                                
*** TODO Item2.2
```

and notice how the first `TODO` should be `DONE` since it's 100% completed. The above code provided in the Org-mode manual could not achieve this effect.

Is there some additional commands I can put in the Init file to make this work?

Comment: FWIW, it works perfectly for me. I change states of third-level items and the TODO state of the second level items is changed appropriately (as well as the statistics cookie) and si is the state/cookie at the top level. So I'm not sure why you re not getting this behavior. What version of Org mode are you running? Are you changing the state with `C-c t`?

Comment: I'm using org version 20200316. And yes I am changing states with *C-c C-t*

Comment: I did mean `C-c C-t` - sorry for the typo. The only thing I can think of is that somehow the hook has not been modified. Can you do `C-h v org-after-todo-statistics-hook RET` and see whether it includes the function above?

Comment: One more thing: can you try it with `emacs -q`? Evaluate the above code somehow (`C-x C-e` will evaluate each s-expression if you put the cursor after the closing paren) and then try cycling through states. If it works, something in your init file is causing the problem: bisect it to ffigure out what.

Comment: You are right, the hook was not added properly, even though I copied the commands exactly to my Init file. What should I do in this case to address this issue? I'm very new to Emacs so I probably didn't set up the Init file correctly.

Comment: Just realized there was a typo in my command so the hook didn't find the function. Thank you for helping me debugging the issue @NickD